# Show RadioButton for each row with validation asp.net mvc 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Using - ASP.NET MVC 4

UI is like -

```
Select            Product Name

RadioButton       Product 1
RadioButton       Product 2
RadioButton       Product 3

Submit Button
```

On submit button click i need to validate whether radiobutton selected or not.
If not, shows message - Please select one product.

If selected, then in the controller, pass the selected Product name.

How can we achieve this in MVC 4?

Comment: have you any markup to share so far?

Comment: dont have any markup yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your model has a property `Product`

```
[Required(ErrorMessage="Please select a product")]
public string Product { get; set; }
```

The in the view

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Product, "Product 1", new { id = "Product1" })
<label for="Product1">Product 1</label>
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Product, "Product 2", new { id = "Product2" })
<label for="Product2">Product 2</label>
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Product, "Product 3", new { id = "Product3" })
<label for="Product3">Product 3</label>
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Product)
```

Comment: ya ok, but then on Submit click, how do i pass the selected product?

Comment: When you post back your model, the value of property `Product` contains either "Product 1", "Product 2" or "Product 3" depending which option was selected. I assume you not understanding the basics of MVC so you should post the model and the controller methods.